# Compare data across id

Tags: python, sas

Hi what I want to do group by id if variables page and step within the ID are the same.

Example:
[image]

So here you can see that id 2(raw white) and 4 (green), has the exact same page and steps.

Example 2 - here you can also see how I want my id_group variable:
[image] 
´

As you can see the group id_group 11 and 12 is giving to two groups that are actaully the same in the page and step variable.

The question is therefore - How do I dynamically assign the same "group" id if the group of the page and step variables are the same within the id ?

Is this even possible in SAS? if its not possible in SAS. Python can do.

Comment: May I know what is SAS?

Comment: it is a programming language: http://www.sas.com

Comment: Resort your data so that you use `BY PAGE STEP`.

Answer (score 1):

In SAS, you can use what's known as a double DOW loop (Google it if you want more information).  This loops through the source table twice, the first time to determine which IDs have the same value for PAGE and STEP, and set a GROUP_ID flag. The second time assigns the GROUP_ID to all records with that ID.

```
data have;
input page step id;
datalines;
1 1 1
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
1 1 2
2 2 2
3 3 2
5 1 3
6 2 3
1 1 4
2 2 4
3 3 4
;
run;

data want;
do until(last.id);
set have;
by id;
if first.id then do; /* reset counts when id changes */
    _count=0;
    _same=0;
    end;
_count+1;  /* count number of records per id*/
_same+(page=step); /* count number of times page = step */
if last.id and _count=_same then do;
    _flag+1; /* if count = same then increment _flag by 1 */
    group_id=_flag; 
    end;
drop _: ; /* drop temporary variables */
end;
do until(last.id);
set have;
by id;
output; 
end;
run;
```

Comment: thanks!
You helped me quite far!
The only thing I am missing is giving the other "groups" an group_id,
and if there was a new set of observations there looked like ID=1 then it they should be in the same group. This could be group 2.

Right now, it only assigns to group 1 right?

Comment: Ok, it wasn't totally clear from your question what the result should look like.  I've just tweaked the code so that it increments GROUP_ID by 1 each time a valid result is obtained.

Comment: Sorry if it is abit unclear. I have updated my question with example 2.

Here you can see that if there is a pattern with page and step. I want it assigned to the same group.